# Finger retopology

Tags: retopology, multiresolution

I finished to retopology my character. After use a multires modifier and a shrinkwrap, this weird thing happen. I sculpt the body first, and then joined the fingers. There is the problem. But, arrived at this point, is there something can I do?[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Have you checked for inverted normals? - Turn on the Face Orientation overlay on the Viewport Overlay menu.